# How to change mustache template data dynamically

Tags: php, templates, helper, mustache

I have just started working with Mustache template engine. I am currently using PHP implementation of it (https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki). I am using helpers to manipulate the way data is rendered.

```
$data = array("name" => "abhilash");
$template = "Hello {{name}}, {{#bold}}Welcome{{/bold}}";

$m =  new Mustache_Engine(array(
  "helpers" => array(
    "bold" => function($content) {
      return "<b>$content</b>";
    })));
$html = $m->render($template, $data);
```

With the help of this I am able to render 'Welcome' with bold font. I would like to know if it is possible to manipulate `$data` with the help of helper function. For example if the template is like below and I have a helper function registered as `dataSource`, I would like to use it to collect some data (say key-value pair) from `datasource_func_name()` and append it to `$data`.

```
{{#dataSource}}datasource_func_name{{/dataSource}}
Hi {{name}}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's normally not how you would use helpers. However, Mustache basically *expects* a data souce, so why not inject it directly?

```
$html = $m->render($template, $dataSource);
```

Comment: Hi Laurent, I understand that it is not meant for providing datasource. Actually I am trying to build a framework (in which mustache is responsible for rendering data). In it I wanted to add support for the template to indicate the data source module name and the framework would take care of collecting data from this data source and feed it back to template. I thought helpers would be a better way to do so without modifying Mustache code.

Comment: He's telling you how to do it :) Mustache shouldn't be fetching data. The data should be fetched and given to mustache.